# Problem with LuaLaTeX and OTF font

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I have a problem using a special symbol font in OTF format with LuaLaTeX. The font itself is correctly installed and found during compilation. But the LOG file states that chars are missing (in fact all chars). An example message looks like:

```
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font
[/Library/Fonts/TokyoNew-Regular.otf]:mode=node;+tlig;!
```

or

```
Missing character: There is no a (U+0061) in font TokyoNew-Regular!
```

I can use the same font correctly in Illustrator -- all chars are there.

BTW does there exist a package for displaying all chars in a font (working with LuaLaTeX)?

Any ideas?

Ulrich

P.S.
Tested with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\newfontface\Tokyo{TokyoNew-Regular}
%\newfontfamily\Tokyo{TokyoNew}
\begin{document}
{\Tokyo abcdef1234}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the lua file of the font (in `\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl`). And does it work with xelatex?

Comment: There two files tokyoneu-regular.lua and tokyoneu-regular.luc. Same behavior in XeLaTeX.

Comment: But only one is a lua file. Did you open it and check the characters?

Comment: O.k., I don't understand the Lua file. But if I compile the single char "Z" I got the same missing char message. But as I understand the char is in the lua file: `[983099]={
   ["boundingbox"]=4,
   ["index"]=59,
   ["name"]="Z",
   ["unicode"]=90,
   ["width"]=1000,
  },`

Comment: `[983099]` is the wrong number, to be accessible as `Z` it should be listed under `[90]`. Did you try with xelatex?

Comment: Yes, same behavior. The file was generated automatically -- what can I do that it will be generated automatically correct?

Comment: It is a strong indication that the font is faulty if it does't work with xelatex too.

Comment: I just saw that you are writing that it is a symbol font. In this case it is not so surprising that unicode positions are empty. Try e.g. \char 983099 to get the char stored there.

Comment: O.k. this does work but is not practical. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well symbol fonts -- may this be chess fonts, or marvosym, or some other set -- normally require from you to write some package that access the glyphs through macros.

Comment: Does it work with xelatex?